# SQL Count records within a month using a unix timestamp

Tags: mysql, sql, datetime, group-by, timestamp

I'm trying to return the count of records within each month and group the result by month / year.

Schema looks something like this:

```
id    title    timestamp
```

I've been searching around but I can't get the result as I expect it. Thanks.

Comment: You want to count `Jan/2010` and `Jan/2011` separately, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Format the timestamp, then group by it.

Group by Month:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.timestamp, "%Y-%m") AS "_Month", COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable as t
GROUP BY _Month;
```

Group by Year:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(t.timestamp, "%Y") AS "_Year", COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable as t
GROUP BY _Year;
```

If the timestamp-field is stored as a unixtime-value, just wrap [`FROM_UNIXTIME()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime) around the field:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME(t.timestamp), "%Y") AS "_Year", COUNT(*)
FROM yourtable as t
GROUP BY _Year;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT YEAR(`timestamp`) AS Y, MONTH(`timestamp`) AS M, COUNT(1) AS C
FROM that_table
GROUP BY YEAR(`timestamp`), MONTH(`timestamp`)
ORDER BY YEAR(`timestamp`), MONTH(`timestamp`)
```