# mysql: how to group by date?

Tags: mysql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [SQL Count records within a month using a unix timestamp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160990/sql-count-records-within-a-month-using-a-unix-timestamp)

I have a table like this

```
+--------+------------+         
|    id  | datetime   |  
+--------+------------+   
|      1 | 1313405609 |  
|      1 | 1313144410 |  
|      2 | 1313405550 |  
|      1 | 1313405549 |  
+--------+------------+
```

datetime is php unix time, I want to group row by date(e.g. 20120517) and count every group items.  Because the date of 1313405609,1313405550 and 1313405549 is 20110815, the result I want is:

```
+--------+------------+------------+  
|     id | datetime   |    Count   |  
+--------+------------+------------+  
|      1 | 1313405609 |      2     |  
|      1 | 1313144410 |      1     |   
|      2 | 1313405550 |      1     |  
+--------+------------+------------+
```

how can I do it with sql?

Comment: This might work for you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6160990/sql-count-records-within-a-month-using-a-unix-timestamp

Comment: thank you, that's the answer I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `FROM_UNIXTIME` to convert a unix timestamp to a datetime. Then use `DATE` to get only the date part:

```
select
  id,
  min(datetime) as datetime,
  count(*) as Count
from
  YourTable t
group by
  id,
  date(from_unixtime(datetime))
```

Comment: yes, I need to group by id, thank you for your answer.